# Usage of the equality $P[g(X) \leq y]=P[X \leq h(y)]$ in an example

Tags: probability-distributions, inverse

Theorem:
Let X have a pdf $f_X(x)$ and let Y=g(X), where g is monotonic (either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing) so it has an inverse function X=h(Y). Assume that h has derivative h'(y). Then $f_X(h(y))|h'(y)|$

Proof:
Here is the proof assuming that g is monotonically increasing.

$F_Y(y)=P(Y \leq y)=P[g(X) \leq y]=P[X \leq h(y)]=F_X[h(y)]$

Now differentiate the cdf, letting x=h(y).

$\frac{d}{dy}F_X[h(y)]=h'(y)f_X[h(y)]$

My problem:

I want to apply the equality $P[g(X) \leq y]=P[X \leq h(y)]$ in the proof to an example to show its validity. Here is what I have tried:

If we look at the standard normal distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. Then we apply integration limits 0 to 10 for $x$. We have that $g(X)=x^3$

$\int_{0}^{10} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^-{\frac{x^2}{2}} dx=0.5$

and for the inverse  $\sqrt[3]{x}$  0 to $\sqrt[3]{10}=1.78$

$\int_{0}^{1.78} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^-{\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}^2}{2}} dx=0.466$

But $0.5 \neq 0.466$

What is wrong. Can someone show how I can use the equality $P[g(X) \leq y]=P[X \leq h(y)]$ on this example. And point out what is wrong?

Comment: The density for $\sqrt{X}$ is not what you wrote.  In addition, $g(x) = x^2$ is not monotonic.

Comment: Is it not monotonic on the interval 0 to 10. Would that not hold? Do you know a monotonic function that is not linear?

Comment: And 1.25 and 1.59 cannot be probabilities.

Comment: $P(X^2 \le 10) = P(-\sqrt{10} \le X \le \sqrt{10})$.

Comment: I have updated the question a little after the feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please don't treat image uploading as a quick substitute to [typing out the math](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305).

Comment: I have deleted the image.